# Oracle SQL+ Trigger created, but still doesn't work

Tags: sql, database, oracle, triggers, compilation

I've created a trigger that can add a new row in a table called "Reapprovisionnement" when  the column "Quatite" is updated in the table "Stock"

```
Create or Replace trigger Reap
after update of quantite on stock for each row
when (new.quantite <new.limite)
declare
    x varchar(20);
BEGIN
    select distinct Nom into X
        from produit
        where Code = :new.codeProduit;

    insert into Reapprovisionnement values (X, :new.CodeProduit);
END;
```

This trigger compiles and is created with no errors.

But when I issue

```
Update Stock set Quantite = 0 where CodeProduit = 'det_isis'
```

I get `"Quantite" value 0 is illegal`, so the trigger here should do its job by creating a new Row in "Approvisionnement"; however, when I tried this here's what I get

```
ERROR at line 1:
ORA-04098: trigger 'SYSTEM.REAPROV' is invalid and failed re-validation
```

Usually, I have this error when I create a trigger with compilation errors, but this time the trigger was created normally, with no error or anything wrong.

Comment: you create it as reap and getting a message as reaprov?????

Comment: Oh, yeah right, Sorry guys, Reaprov is an old trigger that i forgot to delete... It works good now :) Thank you RealSpirituals

Answer (score 0):

Posting my comments as answer, since it solved OP's problem.

You create a trigger named REAP and message as REAPROV.

Disable / Delete your old one. And it should work fine.